# algorithm2e comment style

Tags: algorithms, algorithm2e

I wanted to know how to change the comment style in the algorithm2e package. I want to make my comments of a smaller font and a different color:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
\DontPrintSemicolon
\CommentSty{\color{blue}}
  \KwData{Training set $x$}
  $\Delta_{ji}^l := 0$ \tcp*{will be used to compute $\partial x$}
  \tcc{iterate over all training examples}
\caption{Example code}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You need to define a command with an argument giving the font specification and then use the name of this command in the argument for `\SetCommentSty`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\newcommand\mycommfont[1]{\footnotesize\ttfamily\textcolor{blue}{#1}}
\SetCommentSty{mycommfont}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
\DontPrintSemicolon
  \KwData{Training set $x$}
  $\Delta_{ji}^l := 0$ \tcp*{will be used to compute $\partial x$}
  \tcc{iterate over all training examples}
\caption{Example code}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @GonzaloMedina, when I try `\tcp` it adds a new line after the code comment, so my code skips a line. Why is this? I am using `algorithm2e` and the line looks like: `set $cost\_vector \; \vv{c_{p,v}} = \left\lbrace \right\rbrace$\tcp*{will be used to compute $\partial x$}\;`

Comment: How to reduce space between _examples_ and `*/`?

Comment: (for reference: The commenter above ask a [follow-up question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/377678/250119) on how to reduce space before `*/`)

Answer (score 6):

This answer is similar to the one provided by @GonzaloMedina with space adjusted within comments.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\newcommand\mycommfont[1]{\footnotesize\ttfamily\textcolor{blue}{#1}}
\SetCommentSty{mycommfont}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[h]
\DontPrintSemicolon
\SetAlgoLined
\SetNoFillComment
\LinesNotNumbered 
%\SetSideCommentLeft
\tcc{iterate over all training examples}
 \KwData{this text}
 \KwResult{how to write algorithm with \LaTeX2e }
 initialization\;
 \While{not at end of this document}{
  read current \tcp*[l]{will be used to compute $\partial x$}
  \eIf{understand}{
   go to next section \tcp*{will be used to compute $\partial x$}
   current section becomes this one\;
   }{
   go back to the beginning of current section\;
  }
 }
 \caption{How to write algorithms}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]