# algorithm2e error on \SetDataSty

Tags: algorithm2e

Using the `algorithm2e` package I am trying to write an algorithm on a document.
I wish to change the default font used on the `\SetKwData` variables and I am trying to do that by using the `\SetDataSty` function as shown below:

```
\SetAlFnt{\footnotesize}
\SetDataSty{\small\fontfamily{qcr}} % this line causes Extra \endcsname. errors

\SetKwInOut{Input}{Input}
\SetKwInOut{Output}{Output}
\begin{algorithm}[h]
\LinesNumbered

\SetKwData{AVG}{average\_val}


\Input{A tuple $(a,b)$}
\Output{A hashmap $m$}

\BlankLine

\AVG 

\end{algorithm}
```

But I am getting `Extra \endcsname.` errors on the compilation log. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Please write a minimal working example. See [link](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/250119) for more details what it means.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need to put a single control sequence *name* in the \SetDataSty{...}

Comment: Almost duplicate of [algorithms - algorithm2e comment style - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/162207/algorithm2e-comment-style) / [algorithm2e - Reset the default font and style for algoritm2e - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/271685/reset-the-default-font-and-style-for-algoritm2e)

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a command with an argument giving the font specification and then use the name of this command in the argument for `\SetDataSty`:

```
%! TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\begin{document}

\SetAlFnt{\footnotesize}
\newcommand\mydatastyle{\small\fontfamily{qcr}}
\SetDataSty{mydatastyle} % this line does not cause Extra \endcsname. errors

\SetKwInOut{Input}{Input}
\SetKwInOut{Output}{Output}
\begin{algorithm}[h]
\LinesNumbered

\SetKwData{AVG}{averageval}



\Input{A tuple $(a,b)$}
\Output{A hashmap $m$}


\AVG

\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

<sub>first sentence quote nearly-verbatim from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/162208/250119</sub>

Comment: Actually I'm not quite sure if the lack of grouping cause problem or not...?

Comment: Well, i still get the same error

Comment: @ex1led Give MWE. The document I include in my answer does not get any error