# algorithm2e compact \tcc comment

Tags: algorithms, algorithm2e

[Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/162208/105582), the `\tcc{iterate over all training examples}` command, produces a large gap between `examples` and `*/`. Left alignment is fine. But how to reduce the gap and make it compact?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the command `\SetNoFillComment` locally inside an `algorithm` environment or use the global option `nofillcomment` when loading `algorithm2e`.

MWE (borrowed from the linked answer):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\newcommand\mycommfont[1]{\footnotesize\ttfamily\textcolor{blue}{#1}}
\SetCommentSty{mycommfont}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
\DontPrintSemicolon
\SetNoFillComment % <---------------------------
  \KwData{Training set $x$}
  $\Delta_{ji}^l := 0$ \tcp*{will be used to compute $\partial x$}
  \tcc{iterate over all training examples}
\caption{Example code}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]